# Join tables with 'condition' in RDBMS

Tags: database, database-design, join

I have 3 tables:

```
Persons(PersonID, PersonName, PersonAge, PersonType)

Students(StudentID (fk to Persons.PersonID), StudentRank, StudentClassID, ...)

Teachers(TeacherID (fk to Persons.PersonID), TeacherSalary, ...)
```

A person can be only one type: student or teacher. So if I want to list all person with the type (student or teacher), I need to check PersonType of Persons table, then join with corresponding table (Students, Teachers)? Is it good enough? Anyone can give me a better solution?

Edit: I use combo: PHP + MySQL.

**Update**: Structure of tables.

Comment: Do you actually need anything from your students/teachers tables? If not don't worry about it - you can just select from the Persons table with either a case statement on PersonType or, a join to another table if you have a PersonType table which lists the types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The...

```
SELECT * FROM Persons JOIN Students ON Persons.PersonID = Students.StudentID
```

...will **not** return any teachers.

So you don't have to filter on `PersonType` (but *may* want to in more complex cases, if it's indexed in a way that aids performance).

**--- EDIT ---**

OK, so you want to "cram" everything together then sort on `PersonName`. You can do that by carefully filling the "gaps" between two child tables with NULLs:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Persons.*, StudentRank, StudentClassID, NULL TeacherSalary
    FROM Persons JOIN Students ON Persons.PersonID = Students.StudentID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Persons.*, NULL StudentRank, NULL StudentClassID, TeacherSalary
    FROM Persons JOIN Teachers ON Persons.PersonID = Teachers.TeacherID
) Q
ORDER BY PersonName
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I want to list all persons with the type (of course with type's properties) and sort by person name, for example, `"Alice [Student, Rank: 12, Class: 321], Bob [Teacher, Salary: 1200$], Thomas [Student, Rank: 30, Class: 128]"`... How can I do it clearly in practice?

Comment: @JackCood Just do it in separate queries for each person type. Students and teachers have different columns, so they cannot be UNIONed together in a single query (well, not in a very natural way anyway).

Comment: So I can list persons by type only? I can't order all by name?

Comment: Can you give me a better design?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_in_set` than u need not to join the two tables:

```
select p.Personname 
from students s,persons p
where find_in_set(s.Studentid,p.Personid)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two techniques that will help you, they are explained in the info tab under

[class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance)
[shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key)

Your current design reflects much of class table inheritance.  What shared primary key will buy you
is the ability to enforce the one to one nature of the relationship between students and persons, and between teachers and persons.  It will not enforce a mutually exclusive relationship between teachers and students.

With two joins and a union, you can combine these three tables into a view that captures all this data, with NULLs in places that are not applicable.